# Timestamp is null after loading csv file into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, csv, null, timestamp

there is time stamp in my actual csv file but while loading it into mysql every thing is being loaded except the time stamp which remained as null. i am using mysql in phpadmin(i.e xampp),

code used is:

```
<?php
// specify connection info
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
if (!$connect)
{
   die('Could not <span id="IL_AD1" class="IL_AD">
    connect to</span> MySQL: ' . mysql_error());
}

$cid =mysql_select_db('test',$connect); //specify db name

define('CSV_PATH','C:\Users\vijay\Desktop');

$csv_file = CSV_PATH . "\probe.csv"; // Name of your CSV file
$csvfile = fopen($csv_file,"r");
$theData = fgets($csvfile);
$i = 0;
while (!feof($csvfile))
{
   $csv_data[] = fgets($csvfile, 1024);
   $csv_array = explode(",", $csv_data[$i]);
   $insert_csv = array();
   $insert_csv["app_name"] = $csv_array[0];
   $insert_csv["user_id"] = $csv_array[1];
   $insert_csv["timestamp"] = $csv_array[2];
   $insert_csv["event"] = $csv_array[3];
   $insert_csv["feature"] = $csv_array[4];
   $insert_csv["action_name"] = $csv_array[5];
   $insert_csv["qoe_rate"] = $csv_array[6];
   $insert_csv["qoe_rate_description"] = $csv_array[7];
   $query = "insert into csvdata2 (app_name,user_id,timestamp,event,feature,action_name,qoe_rate,qoe_rate_description) VALUES('$insert_csv[app_name]','$insert_csv[user_id]',$insert_csv[timestamp],'$insert_csv[event]','$insert_csv[feature]','$insert_csv[action_name]',$insert_csv[qoe_rate],'$insert_csv[qoe_rate_description]')";
   $n=mysql_query($query);
   echo $n;
   $i++;  
   }
fclose($csvfile);
echo "file data successfully imported to database!!";
mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

How to include the timestamp code so that i would get the exact timestamp data loaded into table without disturbing the other entries...thanks in advance

Comment: Can you print the generated query from $query?

Comment: No one can answer this without knowledge of the contents of the CSV file or the table structure. Some things to consider: 1) Use [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) instead of fgets. 2) Don't use variable expansion, it's prone to errors. Use string concatenation. 3) use the [mysqli extension](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) and not the deprecated mysql extension. 4) Do proper [input escaping](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes

Here

```
  $insert_csv[timestamp]
  $insert_csv[qoe_rate]
```

Try now

```
  $query = "insert into csvdata2 (app_name,user_id,timestamp,event,feature,action_name,qoe_rate,qoe_rate_description) VALUES('$insert_csv[app_name]','$insert_csv[user_id]','$insert_csv[timestamp]','$insert_csv[event]','$insert_csv[feature]','$insert_csv[action_name]','$insert_csv[qoe_rate]','$insert_csv[qoe_rate_description]')";
```

and follow what @Plenka mentioned in comment